# Keep a vertically larger image inside a smaller, size defined div without overflowing

Tags: html, css

If I have an IMG that is 482 pixels in height, but I just want the first/top 200 pixels (with no resize of the image) to appear inside a div, how would I achieve this? Right now all 482 pixels are displaying and it is overhanging the div tag.

```css
.slideshow { width: 1080px; height: 200px; margin: auto }
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dc8abc1d06f8fc5f2e8640379ccb4742?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG" width="1080" height="482" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an overflow rule.

```
.slideshow { width: 1080px; height: 200px; margin: auto
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will hide any content that doesn't fit inside the container.